# change folder permissions from limited account having admin credentials

Tags: windows-xp, windows-domain

I have to assign full control to a specific folder to everyone. Until now I log on into domain with my admin account and I apply my changes. I'd like to know if it's possible using my credential to apply this change from a limited account without logging out and re-logging.

Command line solutions are equally welcomes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Start>All Programs>Accessories and right-click on the command prompt and click "Run As", and run it as an administrator on the computer, which should include your domain admin account.

Then use this command to give the group Everyone full access to the folder C:\temp (in my example) and all the subfolders:

> CACLS c:\temp /E /T /C /G "Everyone":F

Comment: Great! You solved my problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can start programs using different credentials with `runas`:

```
runas /u:Administrator "explorer /separate"

runas /u:Administrator /netonly "explorer /separate"
```

The first actually logs in to the specified account, the second only uses provided credentials for network connections, but keeps your local privileges.

Optionally add `/savecred` to remember the password.

Comment: @eric cartman Glad to help Eric. Thank you for marking the answer, I appreciate it.